# Need clarification on meaning of sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw the [description of poker in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker), in the first line it says:

> Poker is a family of comparing card games in which players wager over which hand is best according to that specific game's rules in ways similar to these rankings.' .

I couldn't understand what they are trying to say from 'which hand is best....' to '......ways similar to these ranking.' I need assistance

Comment: That's a very convoluted, difficult to understand sentence.  *Poker is a family of comparing card games where players wager on whose hand of cards is ranked highest according the rules specific to that particular version of poker.  In most versions the hands are ranked as follows...*  I assume a list of hand rankings follows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was thinking Daniel meant to say *clarification*.

Comment: Or possibly *clarity*.

Comment: The clarity of the cited text would be almost infinitely improved simply by placing the (adjectivally used) present participle "**comparing**" in "scare quotes". Besides which, *almost nobody* would ever say or write *players **wager over** which hand is best* - per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=players+bet+on+which%2Cplayers+wager+over+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplayers%20bet%20on%20which%3B%2Cc0), the idiomatic standard is *players **bet on** which [is best]*.

Comment: I understood it. Thanks for looking out for me guys. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, note the "to these rankings" is a link to a page containing descriptions of poker hands.  So the demonstrative "these rankings" refers to the rankings described if you follow the link.

So we have "players wager"  (They make bets)

"over which hand is best" (the matter that they are betting on is the hands (that is the set of cards that each player is holding))

"according to that specific game's rules"  There are many poker games (draw, stud, hold-em etc) and the rules specify how you decide which hand is best.

"in ways similar [to these rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)"  But most poker games have similar rules: flush beats a straight, "two pairs" beats "one pair" etc. And the linked page lists the standard poker hands.

Comment: Worth noting that a hand is the set of cards that one player holds.